# How to change run and debug VARIABLES font size

Tags: vscode-debugger

As asked, is there a simple way to change the font size of the run and debug VARIABLES?
[image]

"debug.console.fontSize":
"editor.fontsize"
These definitely don't work.
I have tried and searched, but can't find any good solutions, the font is just too small and torturing to look at while debugging.

Comment: you want to change the font size of the subsection heading that says "VARIABLES"? Or of the text inside that subsection (Ex. "special variables", "function variables", "class variables")?

Comment: Everything in the "run and debug" window.